# ImageMagick jpeg quality extremely low

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, imagemagick-convert

I have the following image `188_f.jpg`:

[image]

And the following code:

```
<?php
    $ss = "convert 188_f.jpg -quality 95% -set colorspace RGB -colorspace CMYK 188_f_cmyk.jpg 2>&1";
    echo ">" . $ss . "<br />";
    echo system($ss);
?>
```

When I run this code, I get this image as output:

[image]

Which is indeed in CMYK, but when viewed at 100% there is a significant loss in quality. (Wasn't sure if SE did any conversions when uploading, so I uploaded the above images via FTP so you can examine them directly if needed.)

[image]

I tried moving the quality argument around, with and without the percent sign, and I also looked through the Imagick guide, but I couldn't find any explanation for why the quality goes down. The output file has the same number of pixels.

**EDIT:** Making no other changes to the script except changing the colorspace options, here were the results:

[image]

**EDIT 2:** Also tried multiple different profiles, using this:

```
convert 188_f.jpg -quality 95% -profile profiles\\UncoatedFOGRA29.icc -colorspace CMYK 188_f_cmyk.jpg 2>&
```

None of them got rid of the pixelatedness.

Comment: What happens when you remove the colorspace options?

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colorspace: _“For a more accurate color conversion to or from the linear RGB, CMYK, or grayscale colorspaces, use the [-profile](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#profile) option.”_ – see if that can help. (Don’t ask me what profile names to try though, I have no experience with that.)

Comment: @CBroe I tried multiple different profiles, and they did change the colors slightly, but it was still really pixelated.

Comment: What are you are trying to accomplish? I also point out that, when recompressing a JPEG, you should use the best quality setting possible (100%?) which will, hopefully, use all 1s in the quantization table.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get an output indistinguishable from your original image with the following options passed either to `convert` or `mogrify`:

`-filter Triangle -define filter:support=2 -unsharp 0.25x0.25+8+0.065 -dither None -posterize 136 -quality 82 -define jpeg:fancy-upsampling=off -interlace none -colorspace sRGB -strip`

(ref: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/efficient-image-resizing-with-imagemagick/)

[image]

(left: original - 74.8kB, right: converted - 63kB)